# Create a setting at backend,to print only selected categries at front-end

Tags: widgets

I am making a plugins widget .In back-end when i am clicking on the selected categories that categories only shows in frontend.
I just making code checked categories but after that what to do,i don't know.

```
            if(isset($_POST['exclude_main']))
            {
                //print_r($_POST);
                //echo "sonali";
                $chk=implode(',',$_POST['exclude_main']);
//print_r($chk);exit;
//header("location:http://localhost/wordpress/wp/wordpress/?value=".$chk);
            }?>

<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Thanks Plugin
*/


class wpt_widget extends WP_Widget
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(
            'wpt_widget',
            __('Thanks widget', 'wpt_widget_domain'),

        // Widget description
        array( 'description' => __( 'Thanks widget', 'wpt_widget_domain' ), )
    );
    }
     public function actionWpPrintStyles()
    {
        if (!(false === is_active_widget(false, false, $this->id_base, true)))
        {
            wp_register_style('avhec-widget', AVHEC_PLUGIN_URL . '/css/avh-ec.widget.css', array(), $this->core->version);
            wp_enqueue_style('avhec-widget');
        }
    }
        // Creating widget front-end
        // This is where the action happens
    public function widget( $args, $instance )
    {
             extract($args);

        $selectedonly = $instance['selectedonly'];

        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );
             $style = empty($instance['style']) ? 'list' : $instance['style'];
             $included_cats = '';
        if ($instance['post_category'])
        {
            $post_category = unserialize($instance['post_category']);
            $children = array();
            if (!$instance['selectedonly'])
            {
                foreach ($post_category as $cat_id)
                {
                    $children = array_merge($children, get_term_children($cat_id, 'category'));
                }
            }
            $included_cats = implode(",", array_merge($post_category, $children));
        }
        if ($invert) {
            $inc_exc = 'exclude';
        } else {
            $inc_exc = 'include';
        }
        $cat_args = array($inc_exc => $included_cats);
          $before_title . $title . $after_title;
// before and after widget arguments are defined by themes
    echo $before_widget;
        //echo $this->core->comment;
        //echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;
        echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];

    // This is where you run the code and display the output(browser)
    //echo __( 'Widget done by Plugin!', 'wpb_widget_domain' );
?>
 <?php


    echo $args['after_widget'];
    }

    // Widget Backend

    public function form( $instance )
    {
        //print_r($instance);
        if ( isset( $instance[ 'title' ] ) )
            {
                $title = $instance[ 'title' ];
            }
        else
            {
                $title = __( 'New title', 'wpb_widget_domain' );
            }
            if(isset($instance['exclude_main']))
            {
                $chkbox=$instance['exclude_main'];
            }
            else
            {
                echo "ssssssssssss";
            }

            ?>
    <p>
    <label ><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label>
    <input name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" />

    </p>
    <?php

          // displays the widget admin form
      $instance = wp_parse_args((array) $instance, array('title' => '', 'rssimage' => '', 'depth' => 0));
        // Prepare data for display

        $selected_cats = (avhGetArrayValue($instance, 'post_category') !== '') ? unserialize($instance['post_category']) : false;

        ob_start();
        ?>
<table class="widefat">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col"><?php _e('Category', 'UCE'); ?></th>
                        <th scope="col"><?php _e('content shown', 'UCE'); ?></th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="the-list">
            <?php
            $args=array(
                'hide_empty' => 0,
                'order' => 'ASC'
            );
            $cats = get_categories($args);
            $alt = 0;
            foreach( $cats as $cat ) {
                ?>
                <tr<?php if ( $alt == 1 ) { echo ' class="alternate"'; $alt = 0; } else { $alt = 1; } ?>>
                    <th scope="row"><?php echo $cat->cat_name; //. ' (' . $cat->cat_ID . ')'; ?></th>
 <td><input type="checkbox" name="exclude_main[]" value="<?php echo $cat->cat_name ?>" <?php if ( in_array( '-' . $cat->cat_ID, $options['exclude_main'] ) ) { echo 'checked="true" '; } ?>/></td>
<!-- <input value="' . $object->term_id . '" type="checkbox" name="' . $this->input_name . '[' . $object->term_id . ']" id="' . $input_id . '"' .  ? ' checked="checked"' : "") . '/> </label>

 -->    </tr>

            <?php } ?>
            </table>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name="save" value="save"></td>
                </tr>
            <input type="hidden" name="ksuce" value="true" />

            <?php
       //$this->avh_wp_category_checklist($selected_cats, $this->number);
        ob_end_flush();
        echo '</ul>';
        echo '</p>';

        echo '<p>';
        avh_doWidgetFormCheckbox($this->get_field_id('invert_included'), $this->get_field_name('invert_included'), __('Exclude the selected categories', 'avh-ec'), (bool) avhGetArrayValue($instance, 'invert_included'));
        echo '</p>';

       echo '<input type="hidden" id="' . $this->get_field_id('submit') . '" name="' . $this->get_field_name('submit') . '" value="1" />';
    }

    // Updating widget replacing old instances with new
    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance )
    {
         // update the instance's settings
        if (!isset($new_instance['submit'])) {
            return false;
        }

        $instance = $old_instance;

        $instance['title'] = strip_tags(stripslashes($new_instance['title']));
        $instance['selectedonly'] = isset($new_instance['selectedonly']);
        $instance['count'] = isset($new_instance['count']);
        $instance['hierarchical'] = isset($new_instance['hierarchical']);
        $instance['hide_empty'] = isset($new_instance['hide_empty']);
        $instance['use_desc_for_title'] = isset($new_instance['use_desc_for_title']);
        $instance['sort_column'] = strip_tags(stripslashes($new_instance['sort_column']));
        $instance['sort_order'] = strip_tags(stripslashes($new_instance['sort_order']));
        $instance['style'] = strip_tags(stripslashes($new_instance['style']));
        $instance['rssfeed'] = isset($new_instance['rssfeed']);
        $instance['rssimage'] = strip_tags(stripslashes($new_instance['rssimage']));
        if (array_key_exists('all', $new_instance['post_category'])) {
            $instance['post_category'] = false;
        } else {
            $instance['post_category'] = serialize($new_instance['post_category']);
        }
        $instance['depth'] = (int) $new_instance['depth'];
        if ($instance['depth'] < 0 || 11 < $instance['depth']) {
            $instance['depth'] = 0;
        }
        $instance['invert_included'] = isset($new_instance['invert_included']);

        return $instance;
    }

  public function avh_wp_category_checklist($selected_cats, $number)
    {
        $walker = new AVH_Walker_Category_Checklist();
        $walker->number = $number;
        $walker->input_id = $this->get_field_id('post_category');
        $walker->input_name = $this->get_field_name('post_category');
        $walker->li_id = $this->get_field_id('category--1');

        $args = array('taxonomy' => 'category', 'descendants_and_self' => 0, 'selected_cats' => $selected_cats, 'popular_cats' => array(), 'walker' => $walker, 'checked_ontop' => true, 'popular_cats' => array());

        if (is_array($selected_cats))
        {
            $args['selected_cats'] = $selected_cats;
        } else
         {
            $args['selected_cats'] = array();
        }

        $categories = $this->core->getCategories();
        $_categories_id = $this->core->getCategoriesId($categories);

        // Post process $categories rather than adding an exclude to the get_terms() query to keep the query the same across all posts (for any query cache)
        $checked_categories = array();
        foreach ($args['selected_cats'] as $key => $value)
        {
            if (isset($_categories_id[$key]))
             {
                $category_key = $_categories_id[$key];
                $checked_categories[] = $categories[$category_key];
                unset($categories[$category_key]);
            }
        }

        // Put checked cats on top
        echo $walker->walk($checked_categories, 0, $args);
        // Then the rest of them
        echo $walker->walk($categories, 0, $args);
    }


}

// Class wpt_widget ends here

    // Register and load the widget
    function wpt_load_widget() {
        register_widget( 'wpt_widget' );
    }
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wpt_load_widget' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow, we don´t need all that code (at least I didn´t read it). Let´s look at your problem from a conceptual side.

You want to choose categories on the backend to be shown in the frontend, if I understood you correctly.

The steps would be the following in the backend:

- Build something to select categories in the backend
- Save what you just selected (comma seperated list could be one way) to the database (`wp_options` would be the place to save it to)

In the frontend:

- Retrieve your saved information (a single field from `wp_options`)
- Split your information into an array (`explode()` a comma seperated string)
- Pass this array as a parameter to a query of your choice (`get_posts()` or `WP_Query()` for example)
- Retrieve only posts from the categories and work on with them...